# 'Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java

When trying to check the current version of Java in which I am running, I received the error "java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.".

I am running Windows 7 OS and have downloaded the latest JDK and felt I may have accidentally deleted the java from machine as before I was able to check the Java version using the command "java -version".

What software must I download to get Java working on my machine again?

EDIT:

I have managed to get Java running from my cmd again after ensuring all environment variables pointed to the current Java SDK.

Comment: I just installed Java and still having this issue. Why didn't the install add this if it's necessary? UPDATE: Had to restart vscode and now it sees it :P

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You need to configure your environment variables, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`.

`JAVA_HOME` must contain the path to java, and you should add **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** to `PATH`

Alternatively, you can simply add to your `PATH` the whole path to the bin folder, without the `JAVA_HOME` variable, however, this makes a little more annoying when you need to have more than one java version on your machine (that way you only need to change `JAVA_HOME` and don't even bother with `PATH`)

Comment: in my case i had jdk 7 installed and it worked just fine until i updated to newer jdk 8 version, the solution was to uninstall the old version of jdk

Comment: It works for me after delete the JAVA_HOME and set the whole path to the java bin folder into the first of the Path variable

Comment: I already got a `PATH` variable. Can I change the content without ruining anything else?

Comment: remember to add BOTH variables "JAVA_HOME" and then "PATH", both on upper case

Comment: For some reason in Windows 10, this won't work. Put the full path in `PATH` variable instead of using `%JAVA_HOME%`. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590863/3337089

Comment: @NagabhushanSN `%JAVA_HOME%` just worked for me on Windows 10 using GUI: https://i.imgur.com/Z9EoqCg.png . Before I added the environment variable, I'd get `java is not recognized as an internal or external command` error when I entered `java -version` into the console.

Comment: Notice: Change the PATH variable in the "System Variables" and not the "User Variables".

Comment: I was trying to install Open JDK 11 without having any JDK already installed in the system. %JAVA_HOME% did not work for me in Windows 8. I deleted the JAVA_HOME variable and gave whole path to java bin folder in Path variable and then it worked.

Comment: I had already JAVA_HOME but setting path with bin resolved

Comment: The relevance of the `JAVA_HOME` variable is a tenacious myth. Java 1.0 and 1.1 used this variable but since then (for a quarter century now), this variable is not used by Java at all. Only some 3rd party tools use this variable as a convention to find the Java installation.

Answer (score 211):

For Windows 7:

1. Right click on `My Computer`
2. Select `Properties`
3. Select `Advanced System Settings`
4. Select the `Advanced` tab
5. Select `Environment Variables`
6. Select `Path` under `System Variables`
7. Click on the `Edit` button
8. In Variable value editor paste this at the start of the line

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin;
   ```
9. Click Ok then Ok again
10. Restart command prompt otherwise it won't see the change to the path variable
11. Type `java -version` in the command prompt.

---

**Notes on Step 8:**

1. The version of java in this may be different from the one used here -- this is only an example.
2. There will probably be other values in the path variable. It is really important that you don't delete what's already there. That's why the instructions say to paste the given value at the *start of the line* -- this means that you don't remove the existing value, you just put java before it. This also fixes any problems you'd be getting if an other version of java is also on the path.

**Notes on Step 6:**

1. This sets the path for the computer, not for the individual user. It may be that you're working on a computer which other developers also use, in which case you'd rather set the user variables, rather than the system variables

Comment: This "Restart command prompt otherwise it won't see the change to the path variable"

Comment: don't use ';' for jdk 10

Answer (score 64):

It sounds like you haven't added the right directory to your path.

First find out which directory you've installed Java in. For example, on my box it's in `C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_11`<sup>1</sup>. Once you've found it, try running it directly. For example:

```
c:\> "c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java" -version
```

Once you've definitely got the right version, add the `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

Note that you don't need a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, and haven't for some time. Some tools may use it - and if you're using one of those, then sure, set it - but if you're just using (say) Eclipse and the command-line `java`/`javac` tools, you're fine without it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, this has reminded me that I need to update...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I can't remember the last time I needed it, personally. *Some* tools may - but I'd only start changing the environment when I actually needed to, rather than just as a matter of course. (I'll edit my answer to indicate that.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer however after adding both the path to java in both the "Path" and "JAVA_HOME" environment variables I still seem to be receiving the same error.

Comment: @Karen: Well did you try my first step of running it explicitly? And have you restarted your command prompt after changing your environment variables?

Comment: When I ran _italic_ c:\> "c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java" -version _italic_ it said "java version '1.7.0_11' Java<TM> SE Runtime Environment <build 1.7.0_11-b21> Java HotSpot<TM> Client VM <build 23.6-b04, mixed mode, sharing>

Comment: Yes I have restarted the cmd after changing the environment variables but there seems to have been no change unfortunately.

Comment: @Karen: Are you sure you added the full bin directory to your path? What does your path entry look like?

Comment: @HockeyJ: You don't need `JAVA_HOME` in order to run Java itself successfully. What environment variables *other applications* use is a different matter. Hence "Some tools may use it" in my answer.

Answer (score 60):

Assume, Java/JDK is installed to the folder: *C:\Program Files\Java*:

[image: Java/JDK installation path]

Follow the steps:

1. Goto *Control Panel → System → Advanced system settings → Advanced → Environment variables* (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> for *System* in *Control Panel*)
2. In the *System variables* section click on *New…*
3. In *Variable name* write: `JAVA_HOME`
4. In *Variable value* write: `C:\Program Files\Java\bin`, press *OK*:
   [image: Add JAVA_HOME]
5. In the *System variables* section double click on `Path`
6. Press *New* and write `C:\Program Files\Java\bin`, press *OK*:
   [image: Add Java Path]
7. In *Environment variables* window press *OK*
8. Restart/Run `cmd.exe` and write: `java --version`:
   [image: Java version CMD]

Comment: I just tried with window 10. The command `java --version` does not work but `java -version` works.

Comment: I am really late, but this is the first time I am having an issue with this, my JDK installation is on the C: drive, the project location is on the D:\ drive. I have updated the %JAVA_HOME% to point to JDK'S bin even though it has been there but not pointing directly to \bin, yet  am still presented with the "java is not recognized " message

Answer (score 26):

Search environment variables.
[image]

open the "edit the system environment variables".
then click on "environment variables".
[image]

Under "User variables" click on "Path" then "Edit".
[image]

Find your Java path and click "Edit".
[image]

then paste the path of your java installation folder.
Mostly you can find it on a path similar to this.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin

Then click OK.
now in the start menu, type cmd.
open the command prompt.
type
java -version
If you did it right,it should show something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

For me its start working after putting ,: in the starting of the  system variable path :--
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My solution was to put same value (path to JDK bin folder) in `JAVA_HOME` and `Path`

[image: JAVA_HOME] 
[image: Path]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some more information - e.g. what you actually put into `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` and don't refer to other answers.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, PATH was properly SET but PATHEXT has been cleared by me by mistake with .exe extension. That why window can't find java or anything .exe application from command prompt. Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is on Windows 8.
First copy your Path of java jdk - e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin.

1. Right on the My Computer Icon on the Desktop and Click Properties.
2. Select 'Advanced System Settings' in the left pane.
3. Under 'Advanced' tab, select 'Environment Variables' at the bottom.
4. In System Variables, select 'Path' Variable and edit it.

Paste the path and add a ';' at the end - e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;

Comment: Ensure (;) at the end of existing path before you append.

Answer (score 3):

Restart the command prompt before checking the version of JDK installed. I spent 02 days on it until my problem resolved when I restarted the command prompt before checking javac - version, javac etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but in my case, the reason was because I was running Anaconda terminal instead of the CMD.

After I use CMD and update the path settings as mentioned by all comments above the issue solved on my side.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using a laptop and do not have the <kbd>Pause\Break</kbd> button.
For windows 10 users with 20h2 and above:

1 *<kbd>WIN</kbd> → **type** "About your PC" → scroll at the bottom → Advanced system settings → <kbd>Environment variables</kbd>* **or** *<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → `shell:::{bb06c0e4-d293-4f75-8a90-cb05b6477eee}` to open Classic System Properties → on the left side → Advanced system settings → <kbd>Environment variables</kbd>*

Also for Windows 10 and Windows 7:

1 *<kbd>WIN</kbd> → This PC → properties → Advanced system settings → <kbd>Environment variables</kbd>*

2. In the System variables section click on New…
3. In Variable name write: `JAVA_HOME`
4. In Variable value write: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin`, press <kbd>OK</kbd>

I have taken steps 2-4 from [Vijay Bhatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3139451/vijay-bhatt)

[image: Adding a new system variable in UI]

There is a bit faster way to set a system variable. Run a console (terminal) as an administrator.

General command synax to add a new variable:

```
setx variableName value /M
```

In our example, we would need to set it as

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin" /M`
```

Like this:
[image: Adding a new system variable using admin console]

`/M` - flag specifies to set the variable in the system environment.
After command execution, you should see the message:
`SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`

How can I check that it is added?

1. Close your active terminal;
2. Open your favorite terminal;
3. Type `java -version`.

You should see something similar to this:
[image: Result image]

**Notice:**
User variables can be created w/o having a root (administrator privileges), whereas to create `System variable`; You need to open a **console as a root**.

I have used `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin` as an example, in your case, it could be different from mine.

Answer (score 2):

I opened a new command prompt in Windows 10 after updating the environment variables without closing the old one(To have my commands handy and lazy to type again)
Still, the new cmd window was referring to the previous version of Java.

Then once I closed the all cmd prompts that ran with admin privileges, the new java version was getting reflected.

Comment: Well this is quite know as the cmd does not get update env in real time, it need to get closed and reopened

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just Install the exact bit of java as of your computer. If your PC is 64 bit then install 64 bit java. If it is 32 bit then vice versa :)

Answer (score 1):

I corrected my path variable but **command prompt** need to **Restart** otherwise, it won't be able to verify the change to the path variable. May be helpful for someone like me. so 
"**restart command prompt**"

Answer (score 0):

if you have cygwin installed in the Windows Box, or using UNIX Shell then

```
Issue bash#which java
```

This will tell you whether java is in your classpath or NOT.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the environment variables (`JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`) under user variables, command prompt (run as administrator) will not identify java. For that you need to set environment variables under system variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

System variables:
PATH = /bin folder of your jdk install

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm

Answer (score -1):

Just some extra information for people that have still problems,
instead of editing the path variable of java, delete that part of the path(only the java!!)
and  make a new variable pointing tpo the jdk/jre.

this seemed to work for me.