# java not found in Console2

Tags: java, console, console2

Hi there when in **Console 2** I type in java or java -version and I get the following error

*'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

HOWEVER in my windows command promt java is working fine...

What configuration do I need to do in Console2 to properly find java currently the java JDK resides in my ProgramFiles dir.

Thanks Happy Holidays!
J

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: FIXED forgot the \bin in the path variable...  too much eggnog