# error while running java program

Tags: java

i am facing problem while compiling a java program i am using command promt to run the program . i have kept the file name and class name both same . also i set the path , i have also set the classpath .

the only reason i can come up with is that the may be  the file gets saved with a ".txt" extension inside of a ".java" extensions, as filename.java.txt.

it shows the error

```
javac : file not found <file name.java>
```

if anyone have any idea about this please tell me.

Comment: Make sure "Hide known extensions" is turned off in your OS preferences, and rename your file to fix the extension.

Comment: If one of the responses below solves your problem, make sure to select the check mark near it to mark it as the accepted answer. If neither work, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Notepad, or a similar program to save your files, **surround the entire file name in quotes** in the save bar.

For example, instead of writing

```
program.java
```

Select "All Files" instead of "Text files", and then in the save text box, write

```
"program.java"
```

**How your save file should look:**

[image: How your save should look]

If this is the case, I would recommend using a text editor that is specifically for coding such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Comment: that problem resolved now new problem could not find the main class

Comment: this one also done ,now another one compiled successfully. but while interpreting gives error java is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: If this fixed it, then mark this as accepted. Here is a post on how to fix your most recent problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **Windows Operating System** then give  the file Name in  double quotes  like this

> "MyJavaFile.java"

then press `Save button` , it will save your file with `java` extension