# Java goes missing and unable to run java program

Tags: java, java-8

Sometimes java goes missing from my machine and while compiling or running any java program I receive below message:

'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The problem is that I work on a machine where I do not have admin rights to set up environment variables every time this issue comes up. Also whenever I fix this issue with the help from admin-tech people; after logging off the issue occurs again. Is there any permanent solution available to this problem?

Comment: your admin should probably set up a correct path and java_home in order for your computer to recognize java. [Check this SO question for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Only your admin-tech team can help. and SO is not for these types of questions. Can you relate it to programming ?

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. Actually paths were set up correctly and I was using java without any issue. However as mentioned in the question; it happens randomly and I have to set them up again in order to get them recognized.

Comment: Hello Guys, thanks again for reading and responding on my post. Actually java was automatically got updated from earlier version "1.8.0_101" to "1.8.0_111"; however under environment variables the path was still pointing to older version (1.8.0_101) and that's why the issue occurred. I believe same thing has happened in the past as well as mentioned in the question.I requested for the admin rights and set the path again and it worked. For the users who might refer in future- please don't let java update automatically if you do not have admin rights to set up the environment variables.