# How to use Mobilenium python module with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use the `mobilenium` python package with `selenium` but am getting

> `ImportError: cannot import name 'mobidriver'`

I installed using `pip install mobilenium` and there was no errors. My python code is as follows:

```
from mobilenium import mobidriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't how why but after a install it with `pip install mobilenium` i also have an issue like you and i don't know why ?!

> ImportError: cannot import name 'mobidriver'

I check it and when we install it with `pip` in `site-packages` we have a folder `mobilenium` with two files

```
site-packages/
    mobilenium/
        __init__.py # here we have copyrights
        __version__.py # here we have version of package
```

And it's all, with `pip` we don't install anything  only `copyrights` and `version`

**Installation**

We will install it from [Mobilenium github repository](https://github.com/rafpyprog/Mobilenium)

**Steps**

```
# in your folder where you want to work 
$ git clone https://github.com/rafpyprog/Mobilenium.git

# after this we need to install all packages from `requirements.txt`
$ pip install -r Mobilenium/requirements.txt 

# create a file where you want to work and import from Mobilenium module
from Mobilenium.mobilenium import mobidriver
```

That's all, no errors and mobidriver was imported. I think i help you.

Comment: Thanks mate, import is working now. I'm just following the documentation example and for the line `mob = mobidriver.Firefox(browsermob_binary=browsermob_path)` I get an error `The Browsermob-Proxy server process failed to start` which asks me to check the the file `server.log` for more detailed info. I checked the file and it says  `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file`. Do you know a way around this? Thanks

Comment: try to look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Great! That link helped solve the rest of the issues. Cheers!