# java is not recognized even after setting the path

Tags: java, path

I installed Java JDK then set the path of system environment in advanced setting but still `java` is not recognized in command prompt..

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0g40.png)

Comment: might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @ButiriDan it is the same question then the one from Yogesh.Kathayat.

Comment: Click a couple of times on Move Up button, one of the earlier entries might go wrong. Try also in the console the path you gave + "java -version".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities

- You tried to execute `jawa ...`. 
  In this case, you made a spelling mistake. It is `java` and not `jawa`.
- the directory of `java` (or `java.exe`) is not in your `PATH`. If you use windows try running `set PATH=<C:\Path\to\Java\bin>` and if you use Unix-like systems, try `PATH=/<Path/to/Java/bin>`.

Comment: (I can't verify option 1 because I cannot see the screenshot currently)