# "Java is not recognized as an internal or external command" after installed

Tags: java, windows

When I type `java -version` or `java` in cmd, it throws the error that

> java is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I know that this has already been covered on a post for windows 7. However, I downloaded and installed java (Java SE Development Kit 13.0.1) from oracle, installed the program, and configured the path in environmental variables, system variables to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\`. I've checked the program files and Java is there, so I'm not sure why

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check system environment variable that connected by ';'.
Except for that reason, the situation does not show any problem for me.
Although the path is different, the method is the same as the photograph.

[image: screenshot]

Can you check it first?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the instance of cmd has `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin` in its `PATH`. You can use `echo %PATH%` to print the value of `PATH` to the terminal.

If cmd was already open when you added it then it wouldn't pick up the changes; that's a mistake I've made a number of times. I've also experienced cases in Windows 10 where I had to reopen the system variables editor THEN reopen cmd before the change took effect. I never got to the bottom of that one but I would open the editor to confirm I had added the correct path, then it would start working.