# Java Environment variable setting

Tags: java, javac

"'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command", How to fix this error? This is happened when I am going to run 'javac' command in terminal and I fixed Environment variable.

Environment Variable :
 Path :C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\HP\Desktop\jdk-12.0.2\bin

JAVA_HOME :C:\Users\HP\Desktop\jdk-12.0.2\bin

I have manages to fix the error by setting Environment variable . Thank you for all answers to my question.

Comment: What version of Java did you download? JRE or JDK? You need the JDK to be able to compile.

Comment: I downloaded JDK. here is the my path - "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\jdk-12.0.2\bin"

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include your java_home and your path environment variable? Also include the full command you're running, from which directory you're running it and the result of the attempted run.

Comment: Try changing the order of your `PATH`, so that your JDK is before the `Oracle\Java\javapath`. Also note that your `JAVA_HOME` is not suppose to include `\bin` (the `\bin` is important in the `PATH` though)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PATH variable contains a path to the `bin/` folder containing `javac` of your installed JDK. Sometimes you also have to configure the `JAVA_HOME` env. variable. [here is some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

If you work on windows then environment variables tend to not reload until system restart. To reload the variables you could restart the "Windows explorer" process in the task manager (that's a fast and easy hack if you add new env. variables).

Comment: I set variables path and restart. still It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

open control panel -> system and security -> system -> advanced system settings(on the left)

then on the advanced tab you will find a button says Environment Variables

in the system variables section you will find "Path" choose it then click on edit

click on new and the path of the bin inside your jdk folder
the path on my pc is(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin)

Comment: I already fixed the path correctly. but It doesn't work.