# Can't use 'java' command in IntelliJ terminal when trying to run my main in it

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-14

I'm trying to run my java program using the `java` and `javac` command, but it returns this in the terminal:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 and have JDK 14.1 installed.

Comment: Have you searched other answered questions on the site? This can be a common issue when running Java programs for the first time, after initial setup. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured your system PATH variable?

See https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html.

Comment: Thanks, followed a YouTube tutorial on how to set Path in Windows 10 for the JDK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBHOeI5QB8M