# Cant open jar files with Java

Tags: java, windows-10

I just installed java, but I tried to open the .jar with other programs first, so the double-click defaults to something else and I can't change it back.

java -jar myfile.jar`
Above command returns:

'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Is there a way I can still open/run this?

e: OS is Windows 10.

Also, I downloaded the .jar file; didn't create it myself (if that's relevant) Not sure if it contains an executable (but I think it does).

(also i copied it if thats okay >-<)

Comment: to run Java, you need to include the `bin` directory in the `PATH`  - see: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html

Comment: Also, you can open a `.jar` file with any Zip tool (WinZip, 7zip, etc) as it is just a compressing format

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) Did you try Googling the error message before posting your question?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't set JAVA/bin path into environment variables.

Anyway, you can right click the .jar ->Open with... and open the explorer. Go to the java path/bin and select `javaw.exe` to open with.