# install jenkins, cant open port 8080 in windows 10

Tags: java, jenkins, installation, windows-10, port

I need to install Jenkins on port 8080 (not another).
every solved problem says I should change the port (not an option) and install JDK 8.

I have installed JDK-13.0.2 (64 bit). But whenever I tried to `$ java -version` in cmd, it says `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. But when I open cmd by administrator, I can detect java.

so, which ways I should do best to run Jenkins?
is installing another java will solve or could become a problem in the long run?

thank you

Comment: If port 8080 cannot be opened, this usually means, another process is already listening on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: yeah, @tgdavies. I get the message What I asked was "is there any other way", and I installed java 8, still cannot open port 8080.

Comment: I've been checked port 8080 in the Jenkins' installation process. it wasn't in use @Henry

Comment: solved by `netstat -a -n -o | grep "8080"`. thank you all!