# How to Set JAVA_HOME on Windows 8 for Maven (Help, new to programming) - Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, java-8

I need to install Java and  to install Maven on my computer.

Downloaded lasted Java and JDK.

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1       - /user variable

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin   - / system variable

PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

When I run command prompt (tied as an admin too) I get

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME alone won't fix that. You need to include the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` directory in your PATH. The setting for the system variable JAVA_HOME should not include `\bin` IIRC.

Comment: i did it but still not working

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?

Comment: no, i tried to all that but nothing changes

Comment: @user207421 added but still not working

Comment: @Faeem azaz Bhanej   no tried that but still the same

Comment: So you didn't do it right. Works for me and everybody else. Show what you did.

Comment: @user207421   take a look here  i posted screenshots  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457830/what-can-be-the-reason-on-the-control-panel-java-and-javac-work-but-java-versio